# How to hide extension upgrade notifications?

Tags: user-interface

Is there a way to hide the notification about available updates for our clients i.e all non-admin users?
I find it stressful for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user has 'administer CiviCRM system' permission set the user should get the notification on screen

Comment: In other words, Guillaume, your "non-admin users" are technically admin users.

Comment: that was it! thanks Pradeep.

Answer (score 0):

If you visit the CiviCRM system status page (Administer > Administration Console > System Status) you can choose to hide the notifications.

[image]

Comment: this would only work for me and as soon as I clear all caches which I'm doing 20 times per time to check every single small change, it's really helpul. But thanks William for answering. I want to set it for non admin users.